# Are there any BitTorrent/DHT extensions for multicast peer discovery?

Tags: ipv6, multicast, bittorrent, dht, peer-discovery

Does BitTorrent or its [mainline DHT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mainline_DHT) has any extension for [IPv6](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multicast_address#IPv6) local peer discovery using [multicast](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multicast)?

Comment: relevant wikipedia article: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Local_Peer_Discovery

Answer (score 2):

So far I found [BEP-14](http://www.bittorrent.org/beps/bep_0014.html) *Local Service Discovery (LSD)*, a [SSDP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_Service_Discovery_Protocol)-like protocol, although I don't know how widely it is implemented and used in clients.

Comment: it is supported at least by uTorrent and libtorrent-rasterbar based clients (Deluge, qBittorrent)